# NPE when trying to instantiate Java object from Jython (WAS)

Tags: websphere, jython, wsadmin

Given the class

```java
public class MyObject {
    public MyObject() {
        System.out.println("true = " + true);
    }
}
```

and the jython script

```python
import sys
sys.path.append('my-custom.jar')
from my.custom import *
config = MyObject()
```

I get the following error when running in WAS ND 6 `wsadmin.bat`

> ```
> Running c:\user\jem\projects\gmm/build/deploy/x.py
>     WASX7209I: Connected to process "dmgr" on node dmgr_node using SOAP connector;  The type of process is: DeploymentManager
>     WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "c:\user\jem\projects\gmm/build/deploy/x.py"; exception information:
> ```
>
> com.ibm.bsf.BSFException: exception from Jython:
>           Traceback (innermost last):
>           File "", line 7, in ?
>           java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
>           at org.python.core.PyJavaClass.init_*class*_(PyJavaClass.java)
>           ... about 20 lines clipped ...
>           at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
>           at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:339)
>           at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:94)
>
> ```
>     java.lang.NullPointerException: java.lang.NullPointerException
> ```

Do what now?

UPDATE:

It seems that the whilst inclusion of the jar into `sys.path` was enough to allow the class to be found, it was not sufficient to allow it to be instantiated. If I unzipped the jar into the existing path it worked.

So my new question is, why didn't adding the jar to `sys.path` work? Is it because the jython version is too old? I believe it is v2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, I believe the `sys.path` is used for *directories* containing python modules (or `.class` files), which may be why it works when you unzip the jar. I think what you really want is to put your jar on the *java classpath* instead. This can be done by providing the path to your jar via the `-wsadmin_classpath` option when invoking `wsadmin`.

Comment: I cannot modify the classpath (or rather, I don't want to). This Q/A says what I am attempting should work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730885/how-can-i-add-jars-dynamically-to-jython-inside-script

Answer (score 0):

sys.path is for python class files not java ones. Also os.path is often used in conjunction to make sure you have a valid and full path. I don't know if it is impossible, but I have never had any luck using sys.path (in wsadmin) for python/jython files either, but I might just be doing it incorrectly.