# Import jar API in Jython

Tags: import, jar, jython

I am trying to import a Java API, which is distributed as a jar file. I followed the instructions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1734231/1072062) at a similar question in Stack Overflow, but it didn't work.

In Jython, I did:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append("/path/to/jar/api")
>>> from com.thingmagic import *
Traceback (most recent calls last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: no module named thingmagic
```

Am I missing something or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that I was using only one backslash on the path (I'm developing on Windows), instead of two:

```
sys.path.append("C:\\remember\\to\\use\\two\\backaslashes\\jarName.jar")
```

Comment: which jython version are you using ? This doesn't work on jython 2.7

Comment: @SaranshKejriwal I'm sorry, that was 5 years ago, I don't remember anymore. I was probably using whatever was the latest at the time.

Comment: This doesn't work on 2.7.2 on windows. ANy idea how to import jar in jython

Answer (score 15):

You need to provide the full path of the JAR file. Change

```
sys.path.append("/path/to/jar/api")
```

to

```
sys.path.append("/path/to/jar/api/whatever_the_name_is.jar")
```

Comment: I was already providing the full path, but I figured the problem. Thanks anyway!