# using non-executable jar functions in Python (Django)

Tags: java, python, django, encryption, jar

I have a non-executable JAR file (i.e. jar without main function as far as my java knowledge is concern) which contain a class. Class consist of encryption and decryption methods. I want to create a web application in Django which is going to use this encryption and decryption method.

I searched on google but couldn't find any suitable method which will let me use this methods.

Will appreciate some reading links along with some examples.

Comment: Since the jar is java you are better off writing your own code in java while it's not impossible for python and java to interact (for example using py4j ) it's a lot of complications. What ever encryption/decryption method this java library provides, there is sure to be a python counterpart.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693993/import-jar-api-in-jython
I was thinking about something like this. Is it possible to combine Jython and Django.

Comment: Found this documentation http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/JythonDjango.html
do you think this will work?

Comment: Please elaborate. Why not?